# Array Scanner for loop

Tags: java

I need to fill my array using `Scanner` and for-loops with 10 names and I don't know how.
This is what I have atm:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class qqqqq {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String[] my_friend_names = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};

   for (int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(my_friend_names[i]);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: You should get input from scanner and set array locations...

Comment: specify how many friends you want to add by for (int i = 0; i < "how many"; i++) and in the for loop try my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args)

{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] my_friend_names = new String[];

    for (int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++)
    {
        my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < my_friend_names.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + my_friend_names[i]);
    }
}
```

You should use the scanner to get user input using nextLine() which will get the next line...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an array of type `String` with size `10`.

```
String[] my_friend_names = new String[10];
```

You need to make a for-loop execute 10 times:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
```

In that loop you have to get the input

```
String name=input.nextLine();
```

and you need to add that name to the array.

```
my_friend_names[i]=name;
```

Don't forget to close the for loop here

```
}
```

And last but not least to prevent garbage

```
input.close();
```

Let me know whether it works or not
Happy coding :) -Charlie